# Optimizing online photo gallery for retina devices

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, image, retina-display

I have an existing website (a photo blog) that loads the majority of the photos from Flickr. I'd like to enhance the experience for users with high resolution screens and load higher res versions of photos, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to go.

Since the images in question are not UI elements, there is no sensible way to solve this problem with CSS. That leaves either client side JavaScript, or a server side find-and-replace for specific image patterns (since they come from Flickr, it's easy to detect and easy enough to figure out the url for a double-sized image).

For client side, my concern is that even the regular sized images are 500-800 KB in size, there there can be 10-30 images per gallery, causing lots of excess bandwidth use for retina users.

For server side, it's obviously tricky to determine if the request comes from a retina device or not. One idea I had (which I have yet to test out), was to run a JavaScript function that checks `window.devicePixelRatio` and sets a cookie accordingly, and then on each successive page request the server would know if the device is high res or not. That leaves the entry page with non-retina images, but at least all the next ones will have high res images loaded right away.

Are there any pitfalls to this proposed solution? Are there better ways to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate CSS on server that will have links to both regular size and double-sized images in `background-image` property. This CSS can easily be different for every page by including it in `<style>` tag and referencing classes/ids that only exist on this page. This will deal with traffic issue, since majority of modern browsers don't load pictures for other DPIs.

Other solution (though worse) will be not just set cookie, but load images with JavaScript. This will solve the initial first page issue, but slow down the page rendering a little.